# MongoDB Production Amazon - 3 data nodes per replica set, or 2 data nodes plus a shared arbiter

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 deployment of mongodb (3.4). Things are going well, but the DB size is growing quickly. I am about to shard a large collection in order to begin horizontal scaling (total space needed is 2TB).

So either (ignoring config servers, etc):

**1. Each shard is a replica set with 3 data nodes**

total cost = $1,130 / mo

6x m4.large ($85 ea) + 4x 1TB SSDs ($116 ea) + 2x 1TB magnetic (to save some $$) ($78 ea)

**2. Each shard is a replica set with 2 data nodes, each also using a shared arbiter**

total cost = $809 / mo

4x m4.large ($85 ea) + 4x 1TB SSDs ($116 ea) + 1x arbiter (cheapest machine is $5)

---

Diff is $321/mo

I get the feeling that option 2, in Amazon's hosted environment, using exclusively SSDs, should be quite durable. As far as I can see, the only problem with Option 2 is that if a primary node dies and I failover to the secondary, for that period there is no backup. But I can't actually evaluate the severity of this scenario.

Could Option 2 be mitigated by  attaching a spinning disk to each data node, that will act as a backup volume?

If anyone could provide some advice from experience it would be super helpful, but any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 has no problems in theory; however the more limited redundancy *may* be a problem.

1. About the arbiters:

Yes, you can run multiple arbiters on a single lightweight machine. An arbiter is a very lightweight process, doing little but voting, so you can [run multiple arbiters on a single box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12129651/174843). Each one must be a separate mongod process.

2. About the redundancy:

If you have a 2-data-node replica set, and one of the data nodes fails, then the other one can function as primary (with the vote of the arbiter), so you have resilience there, but you no longer have redundancy.

Whether that is a severe problem or not depends on your ops, how quickly you can fix or replace the failed node. That depends on your monitoring capabilities, your ops staff competence and availability, etc; that's a decision you need to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

With option 1, why you want to have four nodes in replica set? Three is enough. With four nodes, you should have arbiter as fifth, because vote count must be odd.
With those three nodes, every node should be in the different data center, so you have DR and HA.

Minimum to have DR and HA, two data nodes and one arbiter, all in different data centers.

Comment: 2 shards, 4 nodes (TOTAL), so 1 shard + 2 replicas, each

Comment: So, if your replica set is only 2 nodes, you need arbiter.. Without it, your (shard) replica set don't have primary if one node is down (one is not majority when votes are cast). Arbiter don't need (really) any disk space, so it can be very little virtual machine. So, still three DC setup is best. Two DC for data nodes and one for arbiter. Two AWS and one some  cheap VPS provider what have $2/month XS-size VPS available.

Comment: If a shard has two replicas, is this not a replica set containing three nodes?

Comment: If shard have two nodes, it is two node replicaset (primary + secondary). If shard have three nodes, it is three node replicaset (primary + 2xsecondary). With two node replica set, to reach majority, you need two votes and only way to archive that is to have arbiter what's only purpose is vote, not save data or serve clients.

Comment: Good, that means in Option 1 I have three nodes in a replica set, not two.

Comment: One question.. If you have cluster (shards, sharded collections)... Where is your config servers? Three of them? Just having two times three nodes for shards is not enough. You need three nodes more, because you must have config servers and you cannot put two mongod processes to same physical node because one mongod will eat all the free memory...  OK, you can use container base tech. cgroup to "solve" this problem...